# Why chrome override -webkit-appearance Css property?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have this css:

```
a#exampleId {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
   /* -moz-appearance: button;*/
appearance: button;
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en" wtx-context="7AFAB2C8-5844-4EA0-8DF4-32D617786BAD">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <p>TEXT <a id="exampleId" href="google.com">click this </a></p>
        <button> A </button>
    </form>
<body>
</html>
```

And in chrome I see the browser override the -webkit-appearance: button; property:

[image]

Why do chrome override  -webkit-appearance property and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property names with a [vendor prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) are experimental features not generally intended for production use.

When they stop being experimental, the prefix is removed and a non-prefixed version supersedes it.

`-webkit-appearance` is being overridden by `appearance` two lines later.

Comment: That is the thing. I followed this artice: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link
And the accepted answer recommend this css solution.